# SBT- Copy File to Output Classes

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have a `persistence.xml` file in one of my packages (the file is mixed with sources)

I want this copied to:

`target -> scala-2.11 -> classes -> persistence.xml`

**How can I do this with SBT?**

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider adding the file under `src/main/resources`? Those resource are copied to `target/scala-*/classes/`.

Comment: Does it for me, in all my projects.

Comment: Can u add your project structure in the Q along with the sbt version.